# Регулярка на отрицательное или положительное дробное число

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему не получается на рабочем коде запустить эту регулярку? На специальном сайте работает. А вот в коде не хочет. Вот пример регулярки на [специальном сайте](http://regexr.com/3cmvr).

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('body').on('keypress', '.my-ipreg', function()
    {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,5})(?:[\.,]\d{1,3})?$/g, ''));
    );
});
</script>
```

Я пытаюсь реализовать код, который бы допускал к вводу в форму целых или дробных чисел. Причем ввод как положительных (без каких либо знаков), так и отрицательных цифр/чисел (которые будут отличаться начальным тире). Чтоб тире можно было ввести только в самом начале и только один раз. А также к вводу только одной точки. И чтобы точку нельзя было вводить в самом начале.

И при этом **вводить разрешено** только такие числа:

```
0.001
123456.100
-0.1
```

А вот такие числа **запрещено вводить**:

```
012345
00.100
0.1000
0-0.1
.01
.1.-122
0-0
```

На специальном сайте все работает, кроме начального тире.

Из-за чего не работает пример в коде? В чем причина? Как заставить работать метод `replace()` так же исправно, как работает регулярка на специальном сайте?

Comment: Ваша регулярка точно не обрабатывает с минусом в начале. (кстати, тире и минус - это разные вещи)

Comment: почему такой можно `123456.100`, а такой нельзя `0.1000` ?

Comment: @PoyCc Во первых, replace заменяет то, что совпало, поэтому он заменит правильные строки и не заменит не правильные. регулярку надо писать так, что бы она выбирала только некорректные значения. НО почему вы считаете 012345 неправильным вводом ? Из за ведущего нуля, или потому что нет дробной части. Вот если второе - то такую проверку на вводе вы в принципе не сделаете, потому как пока человек будет вводить числа до точки вы их уже будете удалять потому что точки нет ! Так что определитесь с разрешенными числами что бы их можно было ввести символ за символом

Comment: `.on('keypress', ... $(this).val($(this).val().replace ...` за такое руки отрывать надо... Попробуй-ка ввести что-нибудь не в конец поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что ж, я, для разнообразия, постарался составить корректное регулярное выражение для решения этой задачи.

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
/^(0$|-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9]$)?|-?0\.\d*[1-9])$/
```

Вот ссылка на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mO1hS3/1) для проверки.

**Пояснения**:

`0$` - точно 0

`-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9]$)?` - любое число, большее или равное по модулю единицы, в случае наличия дробной части, оканчивающееся на любую цифру, кроме 0.

`-?0\.\d*[1-9]$` - любое дробное число, большее по модулю 0 и меньшее по модулю единицы, оканчивающееся на любую цифру, кроме 0. `$`, в данном случае, взято из-за скобок.

**Вот сниппет для проверки:**

```js
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(0$|-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9]$)?|-?0\.\d*[1-9])$/);
$('.testcase').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).find('.value').text();
  var assert = $(this).find('.assert').data('assert');
  var $result = $(this).find('.result');

  if (pattern.test(value) === assert) {
    $result.addClass('passed').text('passed');
  } else {
    $result.addClass('failed').text('failed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.assert,
.result {
  text-align: right;
}
.result.passed {
  color: forestgreen;
}
.result.failed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Значение</td>
      <td>Ожидание</td>
      <td>Результат</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">10</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-10</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">11233453487305</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-11233453487305</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">4.12</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-4.12</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">2140.0152</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-2140.0152</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">123.23</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-123.23</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0.1</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0.1</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0.01</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0.01</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="true">true</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0-0</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0.</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0.</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">.01</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-.01</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">0.1-122</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-0.1-122</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">5.1.122</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-5.1.122</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">00.100</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-00.100</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">045</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-045</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">15.5500</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="testcase">
      <td class="value">-15.5500</td>
      <td class="assert" data-assert="false">false</td>
      <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Может, просто сравнивать `parseFloat()` с введённым значением?

```
parseFloat( userInput).toString(10) === userInput
```

**Тесты.** Из примеров в вопросе тест не проходит только по `123456.100`, где в конце лишние нули. Но там же, ниже, аналогичный пример с `0.1000` помечен как «запрещённый», так что считаю провалившийся тест опечаткой ТС. Итого, полагаем, все тесты прошли:

```
значение    ожидание    тест
0.001       true        passed
123456.100  true        failed
-0.1        true        passed
012345      false       passed
00.100      false       passed
0.1000      false       passed
0-0.1       false       passed
.01         false       passed
.1.-122     false       passed
0-0         false       passed
```

**Недостаток** этого метода, как верно заметил @VladD, в том, что длинные числа могут не пройти проверку из-за особенностей округления дробный чисел. Например, не пройдёт проверку вполне валидное число:

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

**Попробуйте**, результат проверки выводится по мере того, как печатаете:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("in");
var out = document.getElementById("out");

function check() {
  out.innerHTML = parseFloat( input.value).toString(10) === input.value ? "годится" : "неформат";
}

input.addEventListener("input", check);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Идея офигенная. Но очень гадкие числа через неё не проходят, например, `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

Comment: Действительно, у всех свои недостатки. В пользу решения замечу только, что вероятность ввода такого длинного числа юзером сравнима с коллизиями в md5 или посещением вами сайта ТС ). Если серьёзно, ориентируюсь на «тесты» в вопросе.

Comment: Ваше решение правильное во всех разумных смыслах этого слова, я голосовал за него. (Число из примера — это то, что _реально_ содержится в `double`-переменной, которой присвоили значение `0.1`.)

Comment: в FF разница наступает после `1.100000000000001` (13 нулей, валидно) если добавить ещё один, 14-й ноль в середине.

Comment: Почему у вас `123456.100` ожидается как проходящее проверку а `0.1000` - нет. В чем принципиальная разница?

Comment: @VenZell мопед не мой, тесты из вопроса. Мне это тоже непонятно, и я тоже задал ТС этот же вопрос в комментариях.

Comment: @Sergiks, упс, не заметил

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял вы хотите позволить вводить в поле только числа, а если пользователь вводит какой то неверный символ - удалять его сразу же.

Первое что можно посоветовать  - используйте соответствующий тип поля ввода (для html5):

```
<input type="number" val="">
```

В этом случае некорректные символы вводить не даст сам браузер.

Что касается скрипта. Я не совсем понял суть вашего регулярного выражения, поэтому предлагаю свое.

```
/^-?\d+\.?\d*?$/g
```

Чисто для проверки является ли строка числом (я не учитываю повторяющиеся нули, или начальный ноль, это легче сделать доп условием в скрипте).

Саму функцию удаления неверных символов предлагаю такую: если строка - число, то сохраняем его в атрибут `data-prevval`, иначе достаем из `data-prevval` значение и сохраняем в `value`.

```
<input type="number" class="my-ipreg" data-prevval="" value="">
```

В реализации функции вам надо будет получать введенный символ, помимо текущего значения элемента (так как введенный символ еще не будет добален к значению, когда обработчик будет вызван). Думаю вы сможете написать функцию самостоятельно.